# Auto generate Id in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I want to generate auto id with timestamp and use it in Label by using react. I have used Styled Component for < Label >

```
// Input Error Label
 const Label = styled.label`
  color: ${theme.colors.red.default};
  padding-top: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.55;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
`;


const uniqueId = () => parseInt(Date.now() * Math.random()); 

return (
   <Label id={uniqueId}>{error}</Label>  
)
```

Why it shows error, please see this screenshot.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGPpw.png)

I hope this code helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign `number` as id when accepted type is `string`. Change your `uniqueID` function to this -

```
const uniqueId = () => parseInt(Date.now() * Math.random()).toString();
```

Also change your return function with this -

```
return (
   <Label id={uniqueId()}>{error}</Label>  
)
```

A working code can be seen here

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-zhukovsky-wr3qi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you please create a Codesandbox or paste error here?

Comment: You've to update return as well. See the updated change

Comment: Updated both and getting ---> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: Just updated the codesandbox link to show the functionality

Comment: don't know why it is not working in my case.

Comment: Create a shareable code and I can look into it

Comment: i checked its working fine, i mean the output is correct may b m getting errors bcz of my IDE..
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you declared **uniqueId** as a function and using it as a variable
first solution: call this function

```
<Label id={uniqueId()}>{error}</Label>
```

Second solution: declare it as variable

```
const uniqueId = parseInt(Date.now() * Math.random());
```

then no need to call it, simply use it as variable

```
<Label id={uniqueId}>{error}</Label>
```

Comment: what is the updated code you are using..?

Comment: you have to convert your number to string using this function "toString()"

Comment: when i use ur first solution, m getting this --> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

when m using ur second solution then Errors are like before in screenshot.

Comment: from which library you are using <Label> Tag

Comment: Post Updated with code for Label and m using Styled components

Comment: import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
function App() {

  const Label = styled.label`
  padding-top: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.55;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
`;

  const uniqueId = parseInt(Date.now() * Math.random()); 
  return (
<Label id={uniqueId}>{uniqueId}</Label>  
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: I created a file and test it, it's working fine, kindly check the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
const uniqueId = () => parseInt(Date.now() * Math.random());
```

> Argument type number is not assignable to parameter type string

parseInt expects a string as input, but (Date.now() * Math.random()) returns a
number, I suggest to use Math.round instead that accept a number.

```
return (
  <Label id={uniqueId}>{error}</Label>  
)
```

> Type number is not assignable to type string

my proposal:

```
const uniqueId = () => Math.round(Date.now() * Math.random()).toString();
```